# Session unserialize not working with the Entity id

Tags: session, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

I have an entity implementing Serializable, something like this:

```
class Entity implements \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->name,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->name
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

At some point in the code I get one of this from the database and save it on the session with

```
// $entity is an instance of Entity
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->set('entity', $entity);
```

Then, if I immediately try to get the entity back with

```
$entityFromSession = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get('entity');
```

The entity is a different class and the id is null, but the name property works fine:

```
get_class($entityFromSession); // returns 'Proxies\__CG__\Bundle\Entity\Entity'
$entityFromSession->getId(); // returns null
$entityFromSession->getNome(); // returns the property correctly.
```

**EDIT:** Here is what I get when I do \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity) :

```
object(stdClass)[779]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'Proxies\__CG__\Bundle\Entity\Entity' (length=35)
  public '__IS_PROXY__' => boolean true
  public '__PROXY_INITIALIZED__' => boolean false
  public 'id' => int 44
  public 'name' => string 'Entity Name' (length=11)
```

What? the id info is there (44 is the id of the object in the database. This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve object from the session storage you have detached entity. You need to call:

```
$entityManager->merge($entity);
```

Comment: Great. I knew it would be something as simple as that. Thank you.